# Connection denied with flask_socketio when using CORS on client side

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, cors, flask-socketio

I want to connect from a client to a server using websockets (both on my machine, localhost). I have this simple client side code using flask and I use `flask_cors` to allow for the client to get data from any domain.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

with the following JavaScript.

```js
console.log('opening up websocket connection with socketio');

const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('client connected to websocket server');
});
```

I then have this server side code running on a different port.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_socketio import send

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('client connected.')

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(data):
    print('received a message: ' + data)
    send(f'thanks for sending your message: {data}, i ack it.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Running both of these on my machine and opening up the browser results in a CORs error.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 403 (socket.io, line 0)
[Error] Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 403
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OGwZUb5 due to access control checks.
```

I would've expected the connection to be made and see the connection established on the server side logs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An update: if I have the flask_socketio on the same server serving the client side code just using `io()` works, but trying the different domain will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Flask-CORS is an extension that works on Flask routes. This extension has no knowledge of Socket.IO.

Flask-SocketIO provides its own CORS configuration options. In your case, you should initialize your SocketIO object as follows:

```py
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='http://localhost:8080')
```